# hide wordpress internal path

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

i am using wordpress but by looking at the page source anyone can figure it out that i am using wordpress by looking at the internal file path i.e.

> http://www.domain.com/wp-content/themes//wp-content/themes//filename.php

i wish to rename that to

> http://www.domain.com/core/filename.php

is it possible using .htaccess

Comment: There are many steps to do it, [check this Q&A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/steps-to-take-to-hide-the-fact-a-site-is-using-wordpress/58591#58591)

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**:
The first url(http://www.domain.com/wp-content/themes//wp-content/themes//filename.php) should not exist.
This is a valid url at most: http://www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/SomeTheme/Somefile.php

**Secondly:** 
You can create pages in wp-admin and assign custom templates to them. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates <-- **GUIDE** 
This way you can give the page a name you prefer, without revealing that it is a wordpress originiated web application.

If do not like to do this, workaround can be achieved with .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/themes/filename.php$ http://www.domain.com/core/filename.php [R=301,L]
```